How to pass array with multiple objects to Angular FormControl?
Let's say I have an object with string values like this:
data = { input: '', description: '' }

where input is what user typed, that I grabbed in (change) function and description is what I have programmatically added in the function afterwards.
I'm passing an array of data objects to formControl with this.form.patchValue({control: this.array}) but when I check against it with this.form.get('control').value it returns an array with only first object (array[0]).
How do I get it to return entire array ?

Ensure that you must create the N (number) of the FormGroup instance in your control FormArray based on the number of objects in your array before the patchValue().
this.form = new FormGroup({
  control: new FormArray([]),
});

for (let data of this.array) {
  (this.form.controls['control'] as FormArray).push(
    new FormGroup({
      input: new FormControl(),
      description: new FormControl(),
    })
  );
}

this.form.patchValue({ control: this.array });

You can also assign the value to the FormControl when initializing the FormGroup instance.
for (let data of this.array) {
  (this.form.controls['control'] as FormArray).push(
    new FormGroup({
      input: new FormControl(data.input),
      description: new FormControl(data.description),
    })
  );
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

That seem to be what I'm looking for tho it's only working for array with defined number of objects. If I'm adding new ones the for loop is adding new items on top of those already there so for instance if there's one object in the array, adding 2nd one will make the form array have 3 objects (array[0] + array[0] & array[1]), adding 3rd one will make it have 6 (array[0] + array[0] & array[1] + array[0] & array[1] & array[2]) and so on. Tried reseting the control with this.form.controls['control'].reset() but it only resets previous fields to null, not removing them from the array.

I've got it cleared with const arr = <FormArray>this.form.controls['control']; arr.controls = [];

Although the accepted answer worked for me, I’ve found this solution better.
No need to iterate with for loop every time new control group is added.
I reused following functions to add control groups:
initControlGroup() {
    // initialize the group
    return this._fb.group({
      input: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['']
    });
  }

addData() {
  // add data object to the list
  const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['controlArray'];
  control.push(this.initControlGroup());
}

removeData(i: number) {
  // remove data object from the list
  const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['controlArray'];
  control.removeAt(i);
}

Code adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45249752/8679394
